# "sacrément amoureuse pour dire" / "sacrément amoureuse, de dire" - what's the difference in meaning?

Tags: sens, prépositions

> Mais bon, faut être **sacrément** amoureuse **pour** dire ça candidement sans se rendre compte du message caché.

I think that normally a combination of some adverb like "sacrément/drôlement/bien/plutot" and the preposition "pour" is used when one wants to say "~ must be **very/quite** ~ **to** do ~". So I was surprised to see  the preposition "de" is used in the following sentence, although the meaning of the sentence construct seems like similar, if not the same.

> Ces loups étaient **drôlement** hardis, **de** venir s’attaquer à la caravane ! Ils devaient avoir vraiment très faim.

Is this the same as

> Ces loups étaient **drôlement** hardis **pour** venir s’attaquer à la caravane ! Ils devaient avoir vraiment très faim.

And about the first one, can one say

> Mais bon, faut être **sacrément** amoureuse, **de** dire ça candidement sans se rendre compte du message caché.

Answer (score 2):

Both meanings are very close, and I'd say the main difference is the introducing verb : `falloir` or `être`. `Il faut` calls `pour`, while `être` does not. (thus your last examples do not work)

`être` does not call `pour` and conveys supposition and observation, with an logical inversion, because the observation is the source of the supposition. Supposition: the wolves were brave, observation, they attacked. The logically inversed sentence really means: I see them attack, so I think they are brave.

In the first sentence, on the other hand, no observation is needed. You can say `Il faut`... `pour` without actually seeing this happen. It conveys a needed state and the consequence of this state. State: to be in love, consequence: saying this.

Please note that in fact, your question is not related to the emphasizing adverbs `sacrément`, `drôlement`, etc. The sentences work without, and the same questions may stem.